# C getting wrong numbers in my array

Tags: c, arrays

So for some reason I'm getting messed up values for my c program

I have

```
int key1[10][3];
int out[4] = {1,0,0,1};
for(i =0;i<10;i++)
{
     for(j=0;j<3;j++)
     {
        key1[i][j] = out[j];
        printf("%d",key1[i][j]);
        //at this point it will print 100
     }
}
    printf("%d",key1[0][0]);
    printf("%d",key1[0][1]);
    printf("%d",key1[0][2]);
// output will be 000
```

This is driving me nuts am i not declaring my arrays properly in memory or something

***I apologize you guys are right i should have just posted code the solution was some error that was nothing relevant to this please forgive me ***

Comment: int out[1,0,0,1], how is this compiling ?

Comment: It might be helpful to state what your expected output is.

Comment: I do not believe this code is your real code, it does not exhibit the problem you claim it does. Voting to close until you provide real code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please do not post junk questions like this. The code you post should be the actual code you ran, not something you entered by hand that you *hope* resembles the code that actually failed.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare and initialize `out` array correctly.

Change

```
int out[1,0,0,1];
```

to

```
int out[4] = {1,0,0,1};
```

Check out [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c).

---

**Update:** For your updated question, it will print correct result if you don't forget to declare `i, j` first.

Check it live: http://ideone.com/Kf5tzC.

Comment: sorry thats not the problem i just made that mistake when retyping the problem

Comment: Don't retype the problem. Copy and paste. You waste everyone's time if you don't post your real code.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths It's not, it's because OP just changed his/her code.

Comment: the entire program is like a 1000 lines of source i had to scale it down

Comment: @bobthecoder: So scale it down, and copy and paste the minimal example you've created that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Yes, I know, I was talking to the OP, your answer was the right one until he changed his question.